# Getting conditional counts on to the same row in MySQL / SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Suppose I have a table, Foo, that looks like this:

```
ID  | Name  | Gender  | Team
1   | Bob   | Male    | A
2   | Amy   | Female  | A
3   | Cat   | Female  | B
4   | Dave  | Male    | B
5   | Evan  | Male    | B
```

If I wanted to get a list of the number of males and females per team **on the same row**, how would I do that?

I know I could do `SELECT COUNT(Name) as "#", Team, Gender FROM foo GROUP BY Team, Gender`, and that's fine for most purpose.

But that would give me 2 rows per team, like below, and that can be a pain.

```
#  Team Gender
1 | A | Male
1 | A | Female
1 | B | Female
2 | B | Male
```

How could I structure the query such that they appear on the same row?

ie,

```
Team | Males | Females
A    |   1   | 1
B    |   2   | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern I was looking for was a Self-Join; the syntax and logic is, in my mind, more elegant then the CASE pattern.

Specifically,

```
SELECT Males.Team, COUNT(Males.id) as "Males", SUM(Males.Points) as "Male Points", 
       COUNT(Females.id) as "Females", SUM(Females.Points) as "Female Points" 
FROM scores as Males 
LEFT JOIN scores as Females ON Males.Team=Females.Team AND Females.Gender="Female" 
WHERE Males.Gender="Male" 
GROUP BY Team
```

Instead of case statements, the groupings I want in different columns get split into their own copies of the same table. You then join the table of Male players with a Table of Female players on the Team, and then group by the Team.

Comment: As far as the logic being "easier to grasp" than Richard's, I think that's very subjective. I understand how both solutions work, but my brain feels more comfortable with Richard's CASE-based solution. That's not to say that your answer is wrong or not as good; I'm just saying that not everyone is going to agree about which of two solutions is more intuitive.

Comment: @ean5533 good point. Edited it to reflect that. I also wonder about performance. I would guess, but do not know, that the JOIN method is faster, as the filtering only happens once, at JOIN time, rather than in each CASE statement, though its conceivable that the SQL engine could optimize for that.

Comment: Performance was one thing I thought about too. I only know the basics of SQL performance tuning, so I don't know either which query would be faster; it may depend heavily on the DBMS. I do know for sure though that if TEAM isn't an indexed column then the join would be horrendously slow. With proper indexes, however, my intuition says that the join method would be faster.

Answer (score 5):

```
select team,
 SUM(case when gender='Male' then 1 else 0 end) Male,
 SUM(case when gender='Female' then 1 else 0 end) Female
from tbl
group by team
```

For the comment

> Imagine now that each row has an arbitrary numeric score associated with it, in a Score column. How would I have 'Male points' and 'Female points? Would that be SUM(case when gender="male" then select points else 0 end) "Male Points"

You're close. The answer is

```
select team,
 SUM(case when gender='Male' then 1 else 0 end) Male,
 SUM(case when gender='Male' then points else 0 end) `Male Points`,
 SUM(case when gender='Female' then 1 else 0 end) Female,
 SUM(case when gender='Female' then points else 0 end) `Female Points`
from tbl
group by team
```

Comment: I'll accept, but I realize I missed a detail in my question: Imagine now that each row has an arbitrary numeric score associated with it, in a Score column. How would I have 'Male points' and 'Female points? Would that be `SUM(case when gender="male" then select points else 0 end) "Male Points"`?